# list indices must be integers or slices, not str (regression code)

Tags: python, regression

i am watching a tutorial on regression and the guy has this code on his screen and it runs smoothly:

```
df = [['Adj. Open','Adj. High','Adj. Low','Adj. Close','Adj. volume',]]
df ['HL_PCT']= (df['Adj. High'] - df['Adj. Close']) / df['Adj. Close'] * 100.0
df ['PCT_change']= (df['Adj. Close']-df['Adj. Open']) / df['Adj. Open'] *100.0

df = df['Adj. Close','HL_PCT','PCT_change','Adj. volume']
```

but when i run the very same code on python, i get the following error on line 2 of the code above (and i am guessing i'll get it again on the next lines) :

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not sr

the funny thing is this very same code works for the guy doing the tutorial. 
thank you.

Comment: Try `df = df[['Adj. Close','HL_PCT','PCT_change','Adj. volume']]` (with double brackets)

Comment: the problem is in the line below the one you've corrected @Carsten